# C++ operator's optimization via templates

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, operator-overloading

So, I have a C++ Matrix class, and there are some overloaded operators(like +, *, %, - atc...), they look like this:

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix& b) const;
```

They are returning the TMP object of type Matrix, and then it's being copied, whinch decreaces the performance.

If I do something like

```
Matrix some = a*b + c*d - (i+j)*m*b; //[1]
```

There are something about 6 copy constructors being called.

So, I saw ppl doing some template metaprogramming, to expand the [1] to something like:

```
Matrix some = ((a*b)+=(c*d))-=(((i+j)*=m)*=b); //[2]
```

The code at [2] gonna call somewhere around 3 copy constructors.(*=, += writing the results to left operand and returns the link for it)

Can you guys pls explain me, how do I do that via templates, or what should I read to understand how to do that.

Comment: _"...and then it's being copied, whinch decreaces the performance."_ Have a read on NRVO/RVO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization . Most modern compilers are now implementing this.

Comment: Besides the compilers return-value optimizations and copy-elision, you could also implement movement operators and `std::move` the returned object.

Comment: "about 6"  Measure how many copy constructors are actually called with an optimised build. You may be surprised.

Comment: Copy elision: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: There are **zero** copy constructors called, not 6. Put some output into the copy constructor, compile with `/O2` or whatever your compiler's flag is called, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I saw in comments, compiller optimize it by itself, but, there are also some moments exists, that can be optimized.

Lets start.

1. First of all, usually, we save the result of overloaded operators via operator=, and if we add a couple of fields in it {bool tmp, bool copied} we can skip the memory coping, its should be looks like this.

.

```
...freeing memory, if needed...
if(!(tmp && !copied)
{
    ...memcpy actions...
}else
{
    ...assigning a pointers to allocated data right to our objects pointers...
    this->arr = a.arr;
    a.copied = true;
}
...other post actions...
```

also we need to change a deconctructor

```
~SomeClass()
{
    if( !(tmp && copied) )//If its not a tmp and not copied then freeing
    {
        ...freeing a memory...
    }//otherwise just skeep
}
```

2. In operators we usually calling an constructor for a result object, but, if one of our objects is tmp, why not to save data inside it, if its possible?

.

```
SomeClass operator+(SomeClass a)
{
    ...some code...
    if(!(tmp || a.tmp))//if there is no tmp object, doing the same, as usual.
    {
        SomeClass res;
        ...some usual code
        res.tmp = true;
        res.copied = false;
        return res;
    }else
    {
        if(tmp)
        {
            ...doing operations and storing them in this...
            return *this;
        }else //"a" is tmp
        {
            ...doing operations and storing them in "a"...
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

so... by those actions we are decreasing the amounght of operations being called, we are saving a memory that would be allocated otherwise, also we are not copying memory from the operator results.

Now, code like this:

```
res = a * n + b * t - k;
```

will allocate memory only for a "a * n" and "b * t", then everything gonna be stored inside tmp objects of those operators results. And finally, we are not coping memory(values) from the tmp object to the "res", we are just simply assigning the pointers to a "tmp" memory(whinch is not gonna be freed).

Answer (score 1):

They keyword to search on is "expression templates".

A lot of things can be achieved simply by using rvalue references, though.

Incidentally, if you're really serious about it you'll want even more rewriting than your example suggests; e.g. multiply and addition steps often want to be combined into a single operation rather than two separate ones.